# grep in forloop not functioning as expected in git-bash

Tags: shell, grep, windows-10, git-bash

I have a collection of stored procedures (SPs) being called in some C# code. I simply want to find which lines in which C# files are using these SPs.

I have installed git-bash, and am working in a Win10 environment.

No matter what I try, grep either spits out nothing, or spits out the entire contents of every file that has a matching record. I simply want the filename
and the line number where SP regex matches.

In a terminal, here is what I have done:

```
procs=( $(cat procs.txt) ) #load the procs into an array

echo ${#procs[@]} #echo the size to make sure each proc got read in separately
output: 235

files=( $(find . -type f -iregex '.*\.cs') ) #load the file paths into an array, 
                                     #this similarly returns a filled out array
output: #over 1000
```

I have also tried this variant which removes the initial './' in the path, thinking that the relative pathing was causing an issue

```
files=( $(find . -type f -iregex '.*\.cs' | sed 's/..//') )
```

The rest is a simple nested for loop:

```
for i in ${procs[@]}
do
   for j in ${files[@]}
   do
      grep -nie "$i" "$j"
   done
done
```

I have tried many other variants of this basic idea, like redirecting the grep output to a text file, adding and subtracting flags, 
quoting and unquoting the variables, and the like.

I also tried this approach, but was similarly unsuccessful

```
for i in ${procs[@]}
do
    grep -r --include='*.cs' -F $i
    #and i also tried
    grep -F $i *
done
```

at this point I am thinking there is something I don't understand about how git-bash works in a windows environment, because it seems like it should have worked by now.

Thanks for your help.

---

**EDIT:**

So after hours of heart-ache I finally got it to work with this:

```
for i in "${!procs[@]}"
do 
   for j in "${!files[@]}"
   do 
      egrep -nH $(echo "${procs[$i]}") $(echo "${files[$j]}") 
   done 
done
```

I looked it up, and my git-bash version is `gnu-bash 4.4.12(1) x86_64-pc-msys`

I'm still not sure why git-bash needs such weird quoting and echoing just to get everything to run properly. On debian linux it worked with just a simple

```
for i in ${procs[@]}
do
   for j in ${files[@]}
   do
       grep $i $j
   done
done
```

Running this version of bash: `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

If anyone can tell me why git-bash behaves so oddly, I would still love to know the answer.

Comment: If just one element in the procs array is an empty string, you get every line of every file.  Do you have any blank lines in procs.txt?

Comment: @stevesliva I checked my procs.txt in notepad++ and each line ends in CR LF with the exception of the last one. So no sadly, that does not seem to be the problem.